# Javascript: Find all parents for element in tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have the objects tree, and i can't found all parents for concrete object id. Imagine i need to add some new field to each parent for object with id = 5. Can someone help please with recursive loop through tree

```js
var tree = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
   {
  id: 3,
  parentId: 1,
  children: [
     {
    id: 5,
    parentId: 3,
    children: []
   }
  ]
 }
  ]
}

console.log(searchTree (tree, 5));

function searchTree (tree, nodeId){
      for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
        if (tree[i].id == nodeId) {
            // it's parent
            console.log(tree[i].id);
            tree[i].newField = true;
            if (tree[i].parentId != null) {
              searchTree(tree, tree[i].parentId);
            }
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: you probably be better ff creating a map of ids

Comment: Please make your snippet **runnable** by removing the syntax errors (`....` and such), assigning the initial object to a variable, etc.

Comment: I've edited start post to right format.

Comment: You say you have to add a new field to "each parent for node with id 5", but in your example you're adding a new field to the "node with id 5"... I don't understand. You need to find "node 5" and then add fields to its parents? or to its children that are parents? How do I know a node is a parent or not (in your example I see all nodes are parents because every one has a child property)?

Answer (score 10):

**data constructors**

People need to stop writing data like this:

```
const tree = 
  { id: 1, parentId: null, children:
    [ { id: 3, parentId: 1, children:
      [ { id: 5, parentId: 3, children: [] } ] } ] }
```

and start writing data using *data constructors*

```js
// "Node" data constructor
const Node = (id, parentId = null, children = Children ()) =>
  ({ id, parentId, children })

// "Children" data constructor
const Children = (...values) =>
  values

// write compound data
const tree =
  Node (1, null, 
    Children (Node (3, 1,
      Children (Node (5, 3)))))

console.log (tree)
// { id: 1, parentId: null, children: [ { id: 3, parentId: 1, children: [ { id: 5, parentId: 3, children: [] } ] } ] }
```

This allows you to separate your mind from details like whether `{}`, or `[]` or even `x => ...` is used to contain your data. I would go just one step further and create a uniform interface with a guaranteed `tag` field – so that it could later be distinguished from other generic datum

It's perfect that stack-snippets butchers the output in this program below. It does *not matter* what the data looks like when *printed out* – **what matters is** it's easy for us humans to read/write in our *program*, and it's easy for our program to *read*/*write*

When/if you need it in a specific format/shape, coerce it into that shape *then*; until that point, keep it nice an easy to work with

```js
const Node = (id, parentId = null, children = Children ()) =>
  ({ tag: Node, id, parentId, children })

const Children = (...values) =>
  ({ tag: Children, values })

// write compound data
const tree =
  Node (1, null, 
    Children (Node (3, 1,
      Children (Node (5, 3)))))

console.log (tree)
// { ... really ugly output, but who cares !.. }
```

---

**let's get searching**

We can write `search` with a simple `loop` helper function – but notice what you're *not* seeing; almost no logic (a single ternary expression is used); no imperative constructs like `for`/`while` or manual iterator incrementing like `i++`; no use of mutators like `push`/`unshift` or effectful functions like `.forEach`; no senseless inspection of `.length` property or direct index reads using `[i]`-style lookups – it's just functions and calls; we don't have to worry about any of that other noise

```js
const Node = (id, parentId = null, children = Children ()) =>
  ({ tag: Node, id, parentId, children })

const Children = (...values) =>
  ({ tag: Children, values })

const tree =
  Node (1, null, 
    Children (Node (3, 1,
      Children (Node (5, 3)))))

const search = (id, tree = null) =>
  {
    const loop = (path, node) =>
      node.id === id
        ? [path]
        : node.children.values.reduce ((acc, child) =>
            acc.concat (loop ([...path, node], child)), [])
    return loop ([], tree)
  }

const paths =
  search (5, tree) 

console.log (paths.map (path => path.map (node => node.id)))
// [ 1, 3 ]
```

So `search` returns an *array* of paths, where each path is an *array* of nodes – why is this the case? In the event a child with an ID of `X` appears in *multiple* locations in the tree, *all* paths to the child will be returned

```js
const Node = (id, parentId = null, children = Children ()) =>
  ({ tag: Node, id, parentId, children })

const Children = (...values) =>
  ({ tag: Children, values })

const tree =
  Node (0, null, Children (
    Node (1, 0, Children (Node (4, 1))),
    Node (2, 0, Children (Node (4, 2))),
    Node (3, 0, Children (Node (4, 3)))))

const search = (id, tree = null) =>
  {
    const loop = (path, node) =>
      node.id === id
        ? [path]
        : node.children.values.reduce ((acc, child) =>
            acc.concat (loop ([...path, node], child)), [])
    return loop ([], tree)
  }
  
const paths =
  search (4, tree) 

console.log (paths.map (path => path.map (node => node.id)))
// [ [ 0, 1 ],
//   [ 0, 2 ],
//   [ 0, 3 ] ]
```

---

**you accidentally wrote the list monad**

The list monad encodes the idea of *ambiguous computations* – that is, the idea of a computation that can return one or more result. Let's make a small change to our program - this is advantageous because `List` is generic and now can be used other places in our program where this kind of computation is essential

If you like this solution, you will probably enjoy reading [my other answers that talk about the list monad](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+list+monad)

```js
const List = (xs = []) =>
  ({
    tag:
      List,
    value:
      xs,
    chain: f =>
      List (xs.reduce ((acc, x) =>
        acc.concat (f (x) .value), []))
  })

const Node = (id, parentId = null, children = Children ()) =>
  ({ tag: Node, id, parentId, children })

const Children = (...values) =>
  List (values)

const search = (id, tree = null) =>
  {
    const loop = (path, node) =>
      node.id === id
        ? List ([path])
        : node.children.chain (child =>
            loop ([...path, node], child))
    return loop ([], tree) .value
  }
  
const tree =
  Node (0, null, Children (
    Node (1, 0, Children (Node (4, 1))),
    Node (2, 0, Children (Node (4, 2))),
    Node (3, 0, Children (Node (4, 3)))))

const paths =
  search (4, tree) 

console.log (paths.map (path => path.map (node => node.id)))
// [ [ 0, 1 ],
//   [ 0, 2 ],
//   [ 0, 3 ] ]
```

Comment: Huh, what's this? I love it. Screw structural literals and give things a name! I wouldn't call it `type` though, rather `tag`. But that's just nitpicking. +100.

Comment: `tag` is more accurate than `type` here; if anything, to avoid misconceptions people already have about types - even better, I’m pretty sure it’s also the name used in *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* (Sussman, Abelson). I’ll update it when I’m at my desk next ^_^

Comment: This breaks when a node has no children.

Comment: @eddy the runnable program has nodes without children; `Node(4,1)`, `Node(4,2)`, ...

Comment: I had to add another check to see whether there were children or not(in which case I return an empty array)

Comment: that's only because you skipped the first part of the answer, _data constructors_, and are probably using a hand-written array where some nodes don't have a `children` property. the solution is to use the data constructors, not to add a null-check for children.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to flatten the tree structure down so you can just look up ids and do a simple while loop

```js
var tree = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
   {
  id: 3,
  parentId: 1,
  children: [
     {
    id: 5,
    parentId: 3,
    children: []
   }
  ]
 }
  ]
}

// We will flatten it down to an object that just holds the id with the object
var lookup = {}
function mapIt (node) {
  lookup[node.id] = node;
  //recursive on all the children
  node.children && node.children.forEach(mapIt);
}
mapIt(tree)

// This takes a node and loops over the lookup hash to get all of the ancestors
function findAncestors (nodeId) {
   var ancestors = []
   var parentId = lookup[nodeId] && lookup[nodeId].parentId
   while(parentId !== undefined) {
     ancestors.unshift(parentId)
     parentId = lookup[parentId] && lookup[parentId].parentId
   }
   return ancestors;
}

// Let us see if it works
console.log("5: ",  findAncestors(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a working recursive function.

Play around with it for a while and you should be golden

```js
var tree = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      parentId: 3,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}

function mapit(node, parent = null) {
  node.parent = parent;
  if (node.children.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      var child = node.children[i];
      mapit(child, node);
    }
  }
}
mapit(tree);
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: isn't it creating circular reference?

Comment: yes it is. It's an example on how to recursively treat the entire tree and leave a reference back to the parent. As long as you don't try to stringify, there should be no problems.

Comment: for loop effectively checks for the node.children.length (i < node.children.length). No need for another if in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

A recursion function isn't that difficult. Remember that you pass the new level onto the function if your parameter isn't met.

```js
var tree = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    parentId: 1,
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      parentId: 3,
      children: [{
        id: 6,
        parentId: 5,
        children: [{
          id: 5,
          parentId: 3,
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]; //wrap first obj in an array too.

searchTree(tree, 5);
console.log(tree);

function searchTree(tree, nodeId) {
  for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (tree[i].id == nodeId) {
      tree[i]; //id found, now add what you need.
      tree[i].newField = "added";
    }//if child has children of its own, continu digging.
    if (tree[i].children != null && tree[i].children.length > 0) {
      searchTree(tree[i].children, nodeId); //pass the original nodeId and if children are present pass the children array to the function.

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's partially works, but for 4-5 deep level the main parent (without parentId) was not found.

Comment: Look at it now, however for large structures the other mapping solutions are more effective.