# Creating a new array from the parents of array child element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
{
  "id": "111",
  "name": "1111",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "22222",
      "name": "2222",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "AAAA",
          "name": "AAAA",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "DDD",
              "name": "DDD"
            },
            {
              "id": "EEE",
              "name": "EEE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "BBBB",
          "name": "BBB",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "FFF",
              "name": "FFF"
            },
            {
              "id": "GGG",
              "name": "GGG",
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "7777",
                  "name": "7777"
                },
                {
                  "id": "8888",
                  "name": "8888"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to create an array with the parents of a child by its ID.

So for example if I wanted to get the path to the child with ID "FFF", then the array would look like something like this:

```
["1111", "2222", "BBB", "FFF"]
```

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: I've reopened the question since I'm not sure if they answer your question. I'll just link the previously duplicate links: [Javascript: Find all parents for element in tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425775) and [How to build the path to each node in a tree recursively - JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892807)

Comment: @adiga Thanks I saw those posts but they're not really what I'm describing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function getItems({ children, ...object }, key, value) {
    var temp;
    if (object[key] === value) return [object];
    if (children) children.some(o => temp = getItems(o, key, value));
    return temp && [object, ...temp];
}

var data = { id: "111", name: "1111", children: [{ id: "22222", name: "2222", children: [{ id: "AAAA", name: "AAAA", children: [{ id: "DDD", name: "DDD" }, { id: "EEE", name: "EEE" }] }, { id: "BBBB", name: "BBB", children: [{ id: "FFF", name: "FFF" }, { id: "GGG", name: "GGG", children: [{ id: "7777", name: "7777" }, { id: "8888", name: "8888" }] }] }] }] };

console.log(getItems(data, 'id', 'FFF'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's pretty good but seeing Mr. Polywhir's reply, specifying the property is also a good idea. so in this case searching by name or id. How would that look in your example?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. Would it be too much to ask how to do this to return the object itself?

Comment: in the result to have an array of id/name objects

Comment: without the children

Comment: so it would look like [{id: 111, name: 111}, {id: 2222, name:2222} etc.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You could implement a recursive search to find all paths and return the correct one when you reach the desired name-value pair.

```js
const isObject = (obj) => obj === Object(obj);

let data = loadData();
let expected = [ '1111', '2222', 'BBB', 'FFF' ];
let actual = findPath(data, 'name', 'FFF');

console.log(JSON.stringify(expected) === JSON.stringify(actual));

function findPath(data, key, value, includeIndicies=false) {
  let opts = { found : null, includeIndicies : includeIndicies };
  findPathInternal(data, key, value, opts, []);
  return opts.found;
}

function findPathInternal(node, key, val, opts, path) {
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      findPathInternal(node[i], key, val, opts, opts.includeIndicies ? path.concat(i) : path);
    }
  } else if (isObject(node)) {
    if (node[key] === val) {
      opts.found = path.concat(val); return; // Exit
    } else {
      let keys = Object.keys(node);
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        findPathInternal(node[keys[i]], key, val, opts, path.concat(node[key]));
      }
    }
  }
};

function loadData() {
  return {
    "id": "111",
    "name": "1111",
    "children": [{
      "id": "22222",
      "name": "2222",
      "children": [{
          "id": "AAAA",
          "name": "AAAA",
          "children": [{
              "id": "DDD",
              "name": "DDD"
            },
            {
              "id": "EEE",
              "name": "EEE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "BBBB",
          "name": "BBB",
          "children": [{
              "id": "FFF",
              "name": "FFF"
            },
            {
              "id": "GGG",
              "name": "GGG",
              "children": [{
                  "id": "7777",
                  "name": "7777"
                },
                {
                  "id": "8888",
                  "name": "8888"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```